# Any View in android studio changes the background color based on device default theme

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, view

whenever I run my app in real device with dark mode on, the color of my views in xml changes automatically but they would be same whenever I use application in Light mode
how can I avoid this and make app run in same colors any all kind of themes?

Comment: What views change exactly?  can you give us an example?

Comment: The background color of my image view is white and text colour is black,but in devices with dark mode on the color changes  background color to black and text color to white

Answer (score 0):

Try and set colors for the same in each theme.xml file. Alternative would be to delete theme folder altogether, set apptheme in manifest to `android:theme="@style/Theme.Design.Light.NoActionBar"` and rebuild project. This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue developer face when designing apps that support light and dark modes. The problem is that some colors in light mode may not look as good in dark mode, and vice versa.

To avoid this issue, you can use Android's built-in color resources that adapt to different themes. Instead of specifying specific color values in your XML layouts, you can use the @color/ notation and define different values for each theme in your values-night/ directory.

For example, you can define a color resource in your res/values/colors.xml file like this:

```
<resources>
    <color name="primary_color">#2196F3</color>
</resources>
```

And then, in your res/values-night/colors.xml file, you can define a different value for the same color like this:

```
<resources>
    <color name="primary_color">#BB86FC</color>
</resources>
```

This way, when the app is running in dark mode, the primary color will be the one defined in res/values-night/colors.xml, and when it's running in light mode, it will be the one described in res/values/colors.xml.

By using this approach, you can ensure that your app looks consistent across different themes and that the colors are always appropriate for the current theme.